# Nginx deploy static file in dynamic sub folder

Tags: nginx, webserver, static-files

My website root (/var/www/static.website.ext/public_html) is organized as follows:

```
images
|___ 61
     |___ 6105495099f49473.png
|___5f
     |___ 5fb969a00a4832d2.png
schema
|___ satic_file.png
```

As you can see the folders "61" and "5f" are generated dynamically (when loading the static file) from the name of the image. (first two characters)

My goal is the following:

```
https://static.website.ext/images/6105495099f49473.png  = display 6105495099f49473.png image (located in /images/61/61...)
```

How can I do in Nginx ?
In Apache just use mod_rewrite, or alternatively mount an index.php file in the /images/ folder with a dispatcher.

But the performance would not be (I guess) like distributing directly from Nginx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression `location` to capture the parts of the URI you require to build the path to the files. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
root /var/www/static.website.ext/public_html;

location ~ ^(/images)(/..)(.*)$ {
    try_files $1$2$2$3 =404;
}
```